# Multiple Scrolling Areas in iOS5 Web App

Tags: ios, scroll, web-applications

I've been pretty impressed with Apple's new -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch feature. It works great until I try to create multiple scrolling areas on the same page. In doing so, a lot of random touch events throughout the page get disabled.

I'd like to call all my pages using Javascript/CSS, but the scroll feature is not playing nice with the other touch events.

Is there any way to prevent these touch events from getting disabled, and still have multiple instances of scrolling on a single page? I've tried iScroll and Scrollability, both have the same problem.